# fetchXml from CRM - is it possible to fetch just the "last" record for a linked entity?

Tags: dynamics-crm, fetchxml

I tried using top="1" and an order descending in the linked-entity element, and I still get back multiple records joined.

```
<fetch version="1.0" mapping="logical" >
  <entity name="x" >
    <attribute name="xid" />
    <link-entity alias="d" top="1" name="t" from="xid" to="xid" link-type="outer">
      ...
      <order attribute="xdate" descending="true" />      
    </link-entity>        
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't limit the number of link entities returned. What you could do instead is make link-entity d the entity and entity x the link-entity so you can use `top` as it is intended.